# Spring Boot + Hibernate, improper parsing of POST request with @RequestBody

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

I have a problem with processing incoming POST request and adding data to the database.

**Short description:** There is `Employer` class which has some fields describing an employer, but most importantly it has a list of MANY objects of `Offer` class. This `Offer` class has a list of  MANY objects of `Technology` class.

**My goal:** I want to process a POST request (sample POST request below) and insert provided data into database (PostgreSQL).

Sample POST request:

```
{
  "title": "qwe",
  "location": "qwe",
  "description": "qweqwe",
  "technologies": [
    "t1",
    "t2",
    "t3"
  ],
  "experienceLevel": "INTERN"
}
```

I also have `Offer` class:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "offer")
public class Offer {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "offer_id")
  private Long id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "employer_id")
  private Employer employer;

  @OneToMany(
      mappedBy = "offer",
      cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
  private List<Technology> technologies;

  private String title;
  private String location;
  private String description;
  private ExperienceLevel experienceLevel;

  public void add(Technology technology) {
    if (technologies == null) {
      technologies = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    technologies.add(technology);
    technology.setOffer(this);
  }

  public Offer(String title, String location, String description, ExperienceLevel experienceLevel) {
    this.title = title;
    this.location = location;
    this.description = description;
    this.experienceLevel = experienceLevel;
  }
}
```

and also `Technology` class:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "technology")
public class Technology {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Long id;

  @ManyToOne(
      cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
  @JoinColumn(name = "offer_id")
  private Offer offer;

  @Column(name = "name")
  private String name;

  public Technology(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

along with `Employer` class:

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "employer")
public class Employer {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Long id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employer")
  private List<Offer> offerList;

  @Column(name = "name", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 100)
  private String name;

  @Column(name = "location", nullable = false, length = 100)
  private String location;

  @Column(name = "description")
  private String description;

  @Column(name = "company_size")
  private int companySize;

  public Employer(String name, String location, String description) {
    this.name = name;
    this.location = location;
    this.description = description;
  }

  public Employer(String name, String location, String description, int companySize) {
    this.name = name;
    this.location = location;
    this.description = description;
    this.companySize = companySize;
  }
}
```

Here is my OfferController which is supposed to accept POST request and put everything in database :

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
public class OfferController {

  private OfferService offerService;

  @Autowired
  public OfferController(OfferService offerService) {
    this.offerService = offerService;
  }

  @GetMapping(value = "offers")
  public List<Offer> getAllEmployers() {
    return offerService.getAllOffers();
  }

  @GetMapping(value = "offers/{id}")
  public Offer getEmployer(@PathVariable long id) {
    return offerService.getOfferById(id);
  }

  @PostMapping(value = "offers", consumes = "application/json")
  public void addOffer(@RequestBody Offer offer) {
    Offer offerWithProperTechnologies = new Offer();
    offerService.saveOffer(offer);
  }

  @PutMapping(value = "offers/{id}")
  public void updateOfferById(Offer offer, @PathVariable Long id) {
    offerService.updateOfferById(offer, id);
  }
}
```

**Main problem:** The data is not somehow inserting properly into database (`sample object of Offer is below`). I don't know why data is not sort of inserting recursively, so that it starts from scratch --> First the technology objects get created (their id's should be set based on strategy) --> then each technology should be assigned the corresponding offer --> then the offer should had an id assign to it and it should be saved into database. (I will pass Employer's id on later stage of my project, so it will link me then to proper Employer). What's wrong with this code? Why isn't it working properly? How can I insert this data properly, because it seems like I need an instance offer in database to link it to Technologies and vice versa --> I would need technologies to exist in database to link them to their offer. How can this be done simultaneously?

```
Offer(id=null, employer=null, technologies=[Technology(id=null, offer=null, name=t1), Technology(id=null, offer=null, name=t2), Technology(id=null, offer=null, name=t3)], title=qwe, location=qwe, description=qweqwe, experienceLevel=INTERN)
```